# "C-c C-v" for "View TODO items in a sparse tree" not working

Tags: org-mode

I'm using Emacs (v 24.5.1) on Windows 7. I have a .org file containing some todos. I read [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/orgcard.html) and in various tutorials that `C-c C-v` is for "View TODO items in a sparse tree" (for the current buffer). But for me it does nothing, it only waits for another argument to be provided. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong command. To view TODO items in a sparse tree, you need to use `C-c / t`. The tutorial to refer to does show it correctly. `C-c C-v` is meant for working with code.

Comment: That does do what I want, thanks. However, nothing indicates that `C-c C-v` is for code, it's listed under "TODO Items and Checkboxes". And other tutorials say the same, for example "C-c C-v – show todos in current document" [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org4beginners.html). So I'm still not clear on the usage of `C-c C-v`.

Comment: @arjan: I do believe that is a mistake in the reference side you list. If you look just two headings above 'TODO Items and Checkboxes', you see 'Working with Code (Babel)' which explains the `C-c C-v` usage. The following [pdf](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/refcards/pdf/orgcard.pdf) does contain the correct commands.

Comment: OK, that explains it. There's at least several docs/tutorials where this mistake is repeated (so technically the answer should be those docs and tutorials are wrong).